# Не могу запустить образ докера

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

Не могу запустить образ докер файл

докер файл выглядит вот так:

```
FROM python:3.11.0-slim

WORKDIR /project

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -U pip && \
pip install --no-cache -r requirements.txt


COPY ./app .


ENTRYPOINT ['python', 'dz2.py']
```

при запуске образа выдает ошибку:

```
/bin/sh: 1: [python,: not found
```

в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В параметре `ENTRYPOINT` используется JSON массив. По правилам JSON строки должны быть в двойных кавычках: `["python", ...]`. У вас одинарные, поэтому докер интерпретирует это как командную строку и передаёт в шелл.

Comment: спасибо это решило проблему